# How to catch an OperationCanceledException when using ContinueWith

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-4.0, async-await

I have some code I'm downgrading from .NET 4.5's lovely `async` and `await` keywords to .NET 4.0. I'm using `ContinueWith` to create a continuation similar to the way `await` works.

Basically, my old code was:

```
var tokenSource = newCancellationTokenSource();
var myTask = Task.Run(() =>
{
    return MyStaticClass.DoStuff(tokenSource.Token);
}, tokenSource.Token);
try
{
    var result = await myTask;
    DoStuffWith(result);
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Cancel gracefully.
}
```

(As one might expect, `MyStaticClass.DoStuff(token)` regularly calls `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`.)

My new code looks like this:

```
var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return MyStaticClass.DoStuff(tokenSource.Token);
    }, tokenSource.Token)
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        var param = new object[1];
        param[0] = task.Result;
        // I need to use Invoke here because "DoStuffWith()" does UI stuff.
        Invoke(new MyDelegate(DoStuffWith, param));
    });
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    // Cancel gracefully.
}
```

However, the `OperationCanceledException` is never caught. What's going on? Where do I put my try/catch block?

Comment: Note that you can use await with .NET 4.0 using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cancellation is handled differently from other exceptions. Basically, you can use this pattern:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // The task
}, tokenSource.Token)
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // The normal stuff
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Handle cancellation
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled)
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    // Handle other exceptions
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Or the alternative one:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // The task
}, tokenSource.Token)
.ContinueWith(task =>
{
    switch (task.Status)
    {
    case TaskStatus.RanToCompletion:
        // The normal stuff
        break;
    case TaskStatus.Canceled:
        // Handle cancellation
        break;
    case TaskStatus.Faulted:
        // Handle other exceptions
        break;
    }
});
```

In your case, you're not catching anything because:

- `Task.Factory.StartNew` returns immediately and always succeeds.
- Your continuation always runs
- Accessing [`task.Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) throws an `AggregateException` since the task is canceled
- The exception is not handled by anything since it's thrown from a thread pool thread. Oops. What happens next [depends on the framework version](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx):

  - In .NET < 4.5, the process will be terminated as soon as the failing task is finalized, since you have an unobserved exception.
  - In .NET >= 4.5, the exception will be silently dropped.

Comment: The concepts sheds some light on what might be going wrong but unfortunately either I had poor execution or it did not work for me.