# C# Async/Parallel Programming with Cancellation Tokens

Tags: c#, .net-core, cancellationtokensource, flurl

I have a list of services that implement the `IService` interface. I also have a calculation service that implements the `ICalculator` interface.

**IService**

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<List<Response>> GetSomeDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

**ICalculator**

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    Task<List<Response>> CalculateAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

I want all the services that implement `IService` to run `IService.GetSomeDataAsync()` in parallel and the `ICalculator.CalculateAsync()` to run on the results of each.

```
public async Task<List<Response>> Run()
{
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    var data = await Task.WhenAll(_services.Select(service =>
    {
        var results = service.GetSomeDataAsync(tokenSource.Token);

        var newResults = results.ContinueWith(x =>
        {
            var request = new request
            {
                Data = x.Result
            };

            return _calculator.CalculateAsync(request, tokenSource.Token);
        }, tokenSource.Token);

        return newResults;
    }));

    var response = data.SelectMany(o => o.Result)
        .ToList();

    return response;
}
```

This all works as expected. The calls to `x.Result` and `o.Result` will not lock up the thread because the tasks are completed by the time its called. The issue comes when I try to implement a cancellation token. I want to be able to cancel `Iservice.GetSomeDataAsync()` when it is taking to long. I also goes with out saying that if `IService.GetSomeDataAsync()` gets cancelled then `ICalculator.CalculateAsync()` should not run either.

I set the `CancellationTokenSource` to cancel in 10 seconds. This works but it throws what I believe to be the `OperationCanceledException` but I am not able to move on with the program or catch the error.

The `IService.GetSomeDataAsync()` method looks something like this.

```
public async Task<List<Response>> GetSomeDataAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await "http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/100000/url/http://www.google.co.uk"
            .GetStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    return result;
}
```

> *Note that I am using Flurl for the web request. I pass the `tokenSource.Token` to the method that was passed in via the containing method parameters.

The `ICalculator.CalculateAsync()` method looks something like this.

```
public async Task<List<Response>> CalculateAsync(Request request, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    try
    {
        var result = await "http://slowwly.robertomurray.co.uk/delay/2000/url/http://www.google.co.uk"
            .GetStringAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    return result;
}
```

> *Note that I am using Flurl for the web request. I pass the `tokenSource.Token` to the method that was passed in via the containing method parameters.

So the question is how do I correctly work with the cancellation token to achieve the intended results?

Comment: Does [How to catch an OperationCanceledException when using ContinueWith](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248572/how-to-catch-an-operationcanceledexception-when-using-continuewith) help?

Comment: Question, why are you using ContinueWith at all? your code could be simplified to https://gist.github.com/leftler/cc89893fa4618137c7e76b0af828280f

Comment: @ScottChamberlain because I need each of the results of `GetSomeDataAsync()` to start run in the `CalculateAsync()` as soon as they come back from `GetSomeDataAsync()`. Is there an alternate way to do it?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Let me take that back. I just saw your link. I was getting an error on the await inside the Task.Whenall(). I didn't know you could put async in front of the lambda.

Comment: Seems like Flurl isn't honoring the `CancellationToken`. Have you posted an issue to that project?

Comment: Thanks for the Advice @StephenCleary I was able to solve the issue using the advice from Scott Chamberlain. I will post my solution shortly.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me.

```
public async Task<List<Response>> Run()
{
    var data = await Task.WhenAll(_services.Select(async service =>
    {
        var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

        try
        {
            results = await service.GetSomeDataAsync(tokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return new List<Response>();
        }

        var request = new Request
        {
            Data = results
        };

        try
        {
            return await _calculator.CalculateAsync(request, tokenSource.Token);
        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            return new List<Response>();
        }
    }));

    var response = data
        .SelectMany(responses => responses)
        .ToList();

    return response;
}
```